# A Useful Riley I Tell Ya!

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My Prefix comes in numerous quantities
>
> My Infix is usually written after
>
> My Suffix is what you will cherish and love
>
> My whole is very useful

What am I?

Hint :

> The word is very useful to students too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you:

> EPSON?

My Prefix comes in numerous quantities

> EPS - "earnings per share" are a share of profit, which can vary so must come in different quantities.

My Infix is usually written after

> "PS" is what you would write at the end of correspondence *after* you finished if you needed to add something.

My Suffix is what you will cherish and love

> SON - someone to cherish and love.

My whole is very useful

> EPSON as well as being a brand of printer is apparently derived from ***Son*** of **E**lectronic **P**rinter, so it could also describe any kind of home printer. Very useful, and as your clue says, useful to students who print material for college work etc.

Comment: Absolutely correct :D

Comment: @KevinL Wow - I'm actually a bit surprised. I was 50-50 about the prefix. I found this a genuinely tricky puzzle! I guessed the infix straight away but the others took ages.

Comment: Really? Well, I have to say you did a great job but ROT13 (ol RCF v zrna rcvfbqrf juvpu hfhnyyl pbzrf va inelvat dhnagvgvrf ) :D

Comment: @KevinL Aah. Are you happy with my alternative interpretation?

Comment: That could work too still (quite creative) :D

Answer (score 5):

OK, I'll give it a shot. Probably not what you were looking for, but worth a try I hope.

I guess you could be

> lesson

Which at least *can* be very useful. And matches the hint.

My Prefix comes in numerous quantities:

> less is quantitative and can mean anything from lots or little, depending on reference.

My Infix is usually written after
Bit of a stretch here:

> esso, as es-so, denotes the Spanish province Soria. In Spanish addresses, the province seems to be written last.

My Suffix is what you will cherish and love.

Well, sadly not guaranteed for everybody, but most people who have one cherish and love:

> son

Comment: Nope incorrect unfortunately :)